# Can Aid Another assist someone else, who is also using Aid Another?

Tags: dnd-4e

The Success line of Aid Another reads:

> The target gains a +2 bonus to the next check using the same skill or ability before the end of the assisting creature’s next turn.

Since you must use the same skill check as the person you're aiding, could someone else use Aid Another to assist your Aid Another check?  Are there any rules that support or forbid this?

Some may find this useful when there's more than 5 in the group, since the Aid Another benefits are limited to 4 aides.  This way, with stackable Aid Anothers, the extra individuals can have a hand in boosting the success of the direct aides.

Comment: It seems like an odd choice. Why would that second person use their Aid Another action to boost the third person's Aid Another check, rather than boost the first person's skill check or ability check? Doing so would mean two potential Aid Another actions — out of a potential four — leading to a +4 bonus.

Comment: @Jadasc Adding reasoning for this to my OP.

Comment: @Iszi I can see where you're coming from, although I think that, once you've gotten five or more people helping on one skill check, you might be dealing with a group check or a skill challenge instead.

Comment: @Jadasc I don't disagree, but this question is more targeted at RAW, not RAI.

Comment: @Iszi Absolutely. That's why I'm glad to have this exchange in the comments; my response is RAW, and can be judged as such.

Comment: @Jadasc, one circumstance where this might be useful is if the GM is limiting how many people can aid one particular check.  I don't know if it's RAW or not but I've seen several skill checks where the GM says only 1 person can assist.  In this case it would make sense for the other players to assist the assist, but whether or not that's an option depends on the circumstances for why there was only one assistant to begin with.

Comment: @Valadil The Rules Compendium does say that the DM can do just that. However, that leads down the road of, "If I said only one person can assist, why would I allow a daisy-chain of assistant-assistants?" In those cases, I think the group check or skill challenge might be a better way to get the group involved.

Comment: @Valdil The RC limits Aid Another to a maximum of 4 direct assists, and allows the DM to further restrict this if they so desire.  I imagine if a DM was to do this however, they'd also be ruling against the "daisy chain" Aiding.  However, this is technically wandering into the realm of "houserule" and is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Rules Compendium supports this interpretation. The Aid Another action is a skill or ability check (p.128), which means that it's a viable target for an Aid itself.

Comment: Errata: "However, up to four creatures can use aid another to affect a single check, for a maximum bonus of +8 or a maximum penalty of –4." 

One could argue that these extra Aid Anothers are affecting a single check, albeit indirectly.

Comment: I think that's a valid point to argue, but I think that would fall into DM interpretation, as with my comments on the OP. As the text is written, even with the erratum, the skill check to Aid Another is a different check than the one being Aided, so it's available for its own AA.

Comment: I mean, the extra Aid certainly _affects_ another check, otherwise what would be the point, mechanically?

Comment: Yes, but it affects it by proxy — Player Six gives Player Five an additional +2 on her chance to give Player One an additional +2. (Players Two through Five are presumably aiding Player One.) I think that distinction is important. Actually, this may be the main point of contention — for this to be relevant, you need a player group of six or more, which is bigger than the "standard" party of four or five.

Comment: @Jadasc I don't know about anyone else, but I've commonly run into parties of greater-than-five in the back room of my FLGS, and even in some house games.  For that matter, our own "chat-based" game here is a party of 6.  So, I would definitely say this case happens more often than one may think.

Comment: @okeefe That point could be argued, but at the same time the "single check" still is not affected by more than the specified +8 or -4.